# CoffeeScript code only works after press home menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am using Rails 5. I have a `home_controller` with index action and `root 'home#index'`. There's a button on index.html.erb, i want to press this button call some js code (pop window).

But my coffee script code only was call after i press **Home** menu. So i am wondering `/` and `home#index` are different? Thank you for your help.

**application.html.erb**

```
<nav>
<li><%= link_to "Home", "/"%></li>
</nav>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'stories/stories' %>
```

**home.coffee**

```
modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = ->
    modal.style.display = "block"
span.onclick = ->
    modal.style.display = "none"
window.onclick = (event) ->
    modal.style.display = "none" if event.target == modal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the reason: put the js code after the element defined which means DOM ready callback, here is JQuery DOM ready in CoffeeScript

```
$ ->
    console.log("DOM is ready")
```